# Zooming onto an object and background in OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I am rendering a virtual object on a video feed, and I want to try zooming in on it. Right now, I:

- rotate and translate the camera by where it actually is with respect to the object,
- make a 2D texture of the latest frame filling up the entire screen, and
- draw the object at the origin after multiplying the vertices by a rotation matrix.

The position is a 3D-vector, and the orientations of the object and camera are quaternions.

How can I zoom in on the object while simultaneously magnifying the texture?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using perspective matrix adjust you field of view. Smaller fov bigger the object